# Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) does not working in: 16.0.7726.1049 excel version

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with FileDialog object. On my computer the code run perfectly, but  on other computer does not work. My office version: 16.0.7329.1047, the problematic version is: 16.0.7726.1049.
Only the FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) does not work, the others (openpicker, folderpicker) works perfectly on the older version also.
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Open2_Click()
 Dim objdialog As Object
 Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3
 Set objdialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
 With objdialog
        .Title = "Select the photo of the machine for the PDF report!"
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        If .Show = True Then
           Savepath2.Value = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Else
         Exit Sub
        End If
  End With
  Savepath2.SelStart = Len(Savepath2) + 1
  Savepath2.SetFocus
  Open2.SetFocus
End Sub
```

There is no any error message just nothing happen when I push the open2 button. I have checked the code ran till the end.
I hope some of you have any idea what can be the problem and how can be solved.

Thank you in advance,

Regards,

Robert

Comment: Works fine on mine, but I'm using version 15.  Does using `Application.GetOpenFilename()` instead of `Application.FileDialog` work?

Comment: Did you try to update Office, there was a recent [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/monthly-channel-2018#version-1809-october-16) release

Comment: The problem is that this macro will be used by the whole engineering team, and I can not follow that the each user which office version uses. I will try your suggestion
. I will give you feedback it will be succesful or not.

Thank you in advance!

Regards,

Robert

Comment: I have tried Application.GetOpenFilename() it works perfectly. Thank you for the support. Regards, Robert